# Unable to generate Unique IDs and access them in document.getElementById()

Tags: javascript

```
function printPerson(nop) {
    if (nop == null || nop == 0) {
        document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "";
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i < nop; i++) {
            var element = document.createElement("input");
            var label = document.createElement("Label");
            var button1 = document.createElement("input");
            var button2 = document.createElement("input");
            var br = document.createElement("br");
            label.innerHTML = "User Name :";
            // addition text box
            element.setAttribute("type", "text");
            element.setAttribute("name", "addition");
            element.setAttribute("id", "cal");
            // button 1
            button1.setAttribute("type", "button");
            button1.setAttribute("value", "+");
            button1.setAttribute("onclick", "document.getElementById('cal').value += '+' ");
            // button 2
            button2.setAttribute("type", "button");
            button2.setAttribute("value", "=");
            button2.setAttribute("onclick", "document.getElementById('cal').value = eval(document.getElementById('cal').value)");
            var para = document.getElementById("div1");
            para.appendChild(label);
            para.appendChild(element);
            para.appendChild(br);
            para.appendChild(button1);
            para.appendChild(button2);
            para.appendChild(br);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am trying to create text boxes and buttons based on the user input but I was not able to give unique IDs for each and every dynamically generated fields so the actions are being performed only one first created text box

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
element.setAttribute("id", "cal" + i);
```

The `ids` will be `cal1`, `cal2` and so on.. And hope you will do the same for the `name` attribute.

Comment: That I tried in that how can we access that in document.getElementById, If you try "document.getElementById("cal"+i)" that will return an error

Comment: Rather use jquery and assign class.